# Visual studio developer command prompt freezes after launching 2nodes in windows 10

Tags: ros, ros2, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am unable to run more than 2 nodes in windows10.

The moment I launch more than 2 nodes. The vs developer command prompt freezes.

*Steps I followed*:

> 1. Open visual studio developer command prompt.
> 2. source ros_foxy with command "call ros2_foxy/local_setup.bash"
> 3. build my workspace "my_workspace" with command "colcon build"
> 4. After successful build, i source the workspace
>    "install/local_setup.bash"
> 5. Finally, i launch all the node(5nodes) using launch file "ros2
>    launch mypackage mypackage.py"

*expected behavior* : All nodes should have been launch.

*actual behavior*: Only two nodes are launched.

*Few more inputs*: I am using ros2 inside a windows vm. 8GB RAM, 110GB C:, 4cores.
Once two nodes are launched(out of 5nodes) i am unable to run any other ros2 related programs like rqt, ros bag record/play. But interestingly i can run all apps via commandline other than ros2 related.

I did check the CPU load and memory usage it was well under 60% of utilization.

*My development setup*

> 1. Visual studio : 2019
> 2. Python : 3.8.3
> 3. Windows: 10
> 4. ROS2_Foxy: Patch 6.1
> 5. C++ 11

Any hints or suggestions highly appreciated.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389369/visual-studio-developer-command-prompt-freezes-after-launching-2nodes-in-windows-10/) by [TinyTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39584/tinyturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2021-10-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-25**:
Unless you're running nodes as background processes, not being able to use the terminal after starting a node seems like expected behaviour (as in: it's just a program running, which is blocking).

I believe it would help (others) if you could describe exactly *how* you are starting things, and what you expected to happen (if something else happened).

**Comment by [TinyTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39584/tinyturtle/) on 2021-10-25**:
Even if I run 5 separate instances of vs developer command prompt with each running different nodes. Still I can only run two nodes.

**Comment by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) on 2022-06-20**:
Hi! I guess I have the exact same problem, in fact I created this [post](https://answers.ros.org/question/402008/ros2-windows-node-always-hang/). Did you manage to solve it? If not, are you using dynamic array allocation? Are you sending dynamic array via topic (like an image)? Do you think it is a ros problem or is your code causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to change your **RMW implementation** to **rmw_cyclonedds_cpp** as said [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Working-with-multiple-RMW-implementations.html). For me, this did the trick.

---

Originally posted by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) with karma: 100 on 2022-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1